# modifying tag for the item in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, treeview

is there any way I could modify the the tkinter treeview item tag? I know how to create item with tag with insert command, but when I:

```py
tree.set(tree.selection()[0],0,'some text in red', tags='red')
```

I get `TypeError: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tags'`

The ultimate goal is to change row or column colors...
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The documentation on Treeview ([here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html) for instance) says that there is a method called `item` that can be used to set or retrieve the options of a tree item.

- `tree.item(iid, "tags")` returns the list of tags of the item identified by `iid`
- `tree.item(iid, tags="red")` changes the tags of `iid` to `("red",)`. You can also pass a tuple of tags like `tags=("bold", "red")`.

Comment: Link is broken. Is this expanding existing tags or overwriting them?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for reporting the broken link, I fixed it. It overwrites the tags.

Comment: Yes I discovered last night it overwrites. So first I read existing tags into a list, then append new tag and overwrite.