# Modify the tag of the selected row in python tkinter treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I added the following code (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298711/modifying-tag-for-the-item-in-tkinter-treeview)), however I didn't get the desired solution.

```
def change_colour():
    trv.set(trv.selection()[0],0,tags='changed_tag')        #this causes problem
    trv.tag_configure("changed_tag",foreground="blue",background="yellow")
```

When executed I get this error (from the first line of the function):
`TypeError: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tags'`

My goal is to change the tag of the selected item (in treeview), so it's colour will be changed.

Comment: the solution for this problem was provided in the post you linked; they had the same error

Comment: I know, but I didn't quite understand it, an example of the solution would be very helpful to me.

Comment: i am writing one

Comment: The `set` method doesn't accept a `tags` option.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution myself, for anyone with the same problem:

```
    def high_target():
        selected_item = trv.selection()[0]
        trv.item(selected_item, tags='changed_tag')
        trv.tag_configure("changed_tag",foreground="blue",background="yellow")
```

Comment: You don't need to configure the tag here. Usually it's best to configure the tags at the time that you create the `Treeview` widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this (didn't test it though):

```py
def change_colour(iid):
    trv.item(iid, tags="changed_tag")
    trv.tag_configure("changed_tag", foreground="blue", background="yellow")
```

and where you create your treeview items with `trv.insert`, store the value returned by `trv.insert` in a variable and pass it as an argument to `change_colour`. Example:

```py
iid = trv.insert("", "end", values=("a", "b", "c"))
change_colour(iid)
```

Comment: Basically this changes the tag of every item. I don't want that, instead only the SELECTED item is what I want.

Comment: sorry @KleitonKurti : i misunderstood your question!